# Unable to find the requested CGNS libraries

Tags: c++, cmake, paraview

I am trying to install Paraview.I am following

http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView:Build_And_Install#Install_ParaView

With

```
ccmake $HOME/projects/ParaView
```

I got

```
CMake Error at CMake/FindCGNS.cmake:27 (message):
    Unable to find the requested CGNS libraries.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
    ParaViewCore/VTKExtensions/CGNSReader/CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)

CMake Error at VTK/CMake/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97 (MESSAGE):
    Could NOT find CGNS (missing: CGNS_LIBRARY CGNS_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
    VTK/CMake/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:288 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
    CMake/FindCGNS.cmake:33 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
    ParaViewCore/VTKExtensions/CGNSReader/CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Have you CGNS library installed? If yes, what are paths to its library files and headers?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes,i have changed the path,problem is solved now!